# Email validation not working in LWC lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I have a lightning-input of type="email" to which I'm trying to add a pattern validation. I added regEx as below but it seems to be not working as expected.

Html:

```
<lightning-input name="owner-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" label="Email"

                              variant="label-hidden" maxlength="80" oncontextmenu={handlePaste} onpaste={handlePaste}

                              autocomplete="off" data-id="owner-email" value={varowneremail} onchange={handleChange}

                              pattern={emailRegex} message-when-pattern-mismatch="Enter a valid email address." onblur={checkOwnerEmailvalidations}

                              required></lightning-input>
```

js:

```
emailRegex ="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$";
```

This code is validation the presence of '@' and throwing error as expected.
[image]

But it is not validating the presence of '.' , it is not throwing any validation error in this case.

[image]

Do I need to add anything else in the `emailPattern` to validate '.'?

Comment: Try this: `emailRegex = "[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$";`

Answer (score 1):

In source code, `\.` evaluates to just `.`, which in turn matches any single character. You would need to write `\\.` in order for the regular expression to match a literal `.`. Note that `type="email"` already validates for a valid email per [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822). Your pattern, even after fixing, may exclude valid email addresses.

Comment: I did add \\. but that didn't work, I'm seeing below error in console: Pattern attribute value [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/v: Invalid character in character class

Answer (score 0):

If you define the regex in the LWC JS file, you'll have to use double backslashes as mentioned by sfdcfox. I had a similar issue while back, and the solution was to escape the hyphens which did not denote a range;

`emailRegex = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+\\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$";`

Comment: >> This code is validation the presence of '@' and throwing error as expected. <<


There was `type="email"` set so this was the built-in validation, the custom regex was not validating at all due to the syntax issue with the hyphens.